# Routing with Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify, react-routing

I am developing a spotify clone with the ability to play a preview of the songs and display user's different top tracks and artists. I have already made standalone pages for the website after authorizing with the help spotify-web-api-node package, but i am kinda facing a problem connecting the routers, after i login with spotify i reach my profile page where i have links to other pages, but when i try to go to another page i get an error on the server that it is an invalid authorization code and on the web console, the package throws an error that no access token was provided. I have tried every possible way to correct this but i am not able to do anything. Please help me out. The relevant code as well the whole GitHub repository is linked below:
The Github repository for this project is https://github.com/amoghkapoor/Spotify-Clone

App.js

```js
const code = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("code")

const App = () => {

    return (
        <>
            {code ?
                <Router>
                    <Link to="/tracks">
                        <div style={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
                            <p>Tracks</p>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/">
                        <div style={{ marginBottom: "3rem" }}>
                            <p>Home</p>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            <Profile code={code} />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/tracks">

                            <TopTracks code={code} />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>

                </Router> : <Login />}
        </>
    )
}
```

TopTracks.js

```js
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    client_id: "some client id"
})

const TopTracks = ({ code }) => {
    const accessToken = useAuth(code)

    console.log(accessToken) // undefined in console

    console.log(code) // the correct code as provided by spotify 

    useEffect(() => {
        if (accessToken) {
            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken)
            return
        }

    }, [accessToken])
```

'useAuth' custom Hook

```js
export default function useAuth(code) {
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState()
    const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState()
    const [expiresIn, setExpiresIn] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
                code
            })
            .then(res => {
                setAccessToken(res.data.accessToken)
                setRefreshToken(res.data.refreshToken)
                setExpiresIn(res.data.expiresIn)
                window.history.pushState({}, null, "/")
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // window.location = "/"
                console.log("login error", err)
            })

    }, [code])
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please do try to update your question to include relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we don't need to sift through your entire codebase. Include specific and clear details regarding bugs, issues, behavior, stacktraces, etc...

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the question to include relevant code, thanks for the advice. Hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be persisting your access/refresh tokens anywhere. As soon as the component is unloaded, the data would be discarded. In addition, a sign in code is only usable **once**. If you use it more than once, any OAuth-compliant service will invalidate all tokens related to that code.

You can persist these tokens using [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or another database mechanism.

For the purposes of an example (i.e. use something more secure & permanent than this), I'll use `localStorage`.

To help manage state across multiple views and components, you should make use of a React [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). This allows you to lift common logic higher in your component tree so that it can be reused.

Furthermore, instead of using `setInterval` to refresh the token periodically, you should only perform refresh operations on-demand - that is, refresh it when it expires.

```
// SpotifyAuthContext.js

import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: 'fcecfc72172e4cd267473117a17cbd4d',
});

export const SpotifyAuthContext = React.createContext({
    exchangeCode: () => throw new Error("context not loaded"),
    refreshAccessToken: () => throw new Error("context not loaded"),
    get hasToken: spotifyApi.getAccessToken() !== undefined,
    api: spotifyApi
});

export const useSpotify = () => useContext(SpotifyAuthContext);

function setStoredJSON(id, obj) {
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function getStoredJSON(id, fallbackValue = null) {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(id);
    return storedValue === null
        ? fallbackValue
        : JSON.parse(storedValue);
}

export function SpotifyAuthContextProvider({children}) {
    const [tokenInfo, setTokenInfo] = useState(() => getStoredJSON('myApp:spotify', null))

    const hasToken = tokenInfo !== null

    useEffect(() => {
        if (tokenInfo === null) return; // do nothing, no tokens available

        // attach tokens to `SpotifyWebApi` instance
        spotifyApi.setCredentials({
            accessToken: tokenInfo.accessToken,
            refreshToken: tokenInfo.refreshToken,
        })

        // persist tokens
        setStoredJSON('myApp:spotify', tokenInfo)
    }, [tokenInfo])

    function exchangeCode(code) {
        return axios
            .post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
                code
            })
            .then(res => {
                // TODO: Confirm whether response contains `accessToken` or `access_token`
                const { accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn } = res.data;
                // store expiry time instead of expires in
                setTokenInfo({
                    accessToken,
                    refreshToken,
                    expiresAt: Date.now() + (expiresIn * 1000)
                });
            })
    }

    function refreshAccessToken() {
        return axios
            .post("http://localhost:3001/refresh", {
                refreshToken
            })
            .then(res => {
                const refreshedTokenInfo = {
                     accessToken: res.data.accessToken,
                     // some refreshes may include a new refresh token!
                     refreshToken: res.data.refreshToken || tokenInfo.refreshToken,
                     // store expiry time instead of expires in
                     expiresAt: Date.now() + (res.data.expiresIn * 1000)
                }

                setTokenInfo(refreshedTokenInfo)

                // attach tokens to `SpotifyWebApi` instance
                spotifyApi.setCredentials({
                    accessToken: refreshedTokenInfo.accessToken,
                    refreshToken: refreshedTokenInfo.refreshToken,
                })

                return refreshedTokenInfo
            })
    }

    async function refreshableCall(callApiFunc) {
         if (Date.now() > tokenInfo.expiresAt)
             await refreshAccessToken();

         try {
             return await callApiFunc()
         } catch (err) {
             if (err.name !== "WebapiAuthenticationError")
                 throw err; // rethrow irrelevant errors
         }

         // if here, has an authentication error, try refreshing now
         return refreshAccessToken()
             .then(callApiFunc)
    }

    return (
        <SpotifyAuthContext.Provider value={{
            api: spotifyApi,
            exchangeCode,
            hasToken,
            refreshableCall,
            refreshAccessToken
        }}>
            {children}
        </SpotifyAuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Usage:

```
// TopTracks.js
import useSpotify from '...'

const TopTracks = () => {
    const { api, refreshableCall } = useSpotify()
    const [ tracks, setTracks ] = useState([])
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        let disposed = false
        refreshableCall(() => api.getMyTopTracks()) // <- calls getMyTopTracks, but retry if the token has expired
            .then((res) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setTracks(res.body.items)
                setError(null)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setTracks([])
                setError(err)
            });

        return () => disposed = true
    });

    if (error != null) {
       return <span class="error">{error.message}</span>
    }

    if (tracks.length === 0) {
       return <span class="warning">No tracks found.</span>
    }

    return (<ul>
       {tracks.map((track) => {
           const artists = track.artists
               .map(artist => artist.name)
               .join(', ')

           return (
               <li key={track.id}>
                   <a href={track.preview_url}>
                       {track.name} - {artists}
                   </a>
               </li>
           )
       }
    </ul>)
}
```

```
// Login.js
import useSpotify from '...'

const Login = () => {
    const { exchangeCode } = useSpotify()
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)

    const code = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("code")

    useEffect(() => {
       if (!code) return // no code. do nothing.

       // if here, code available for login
       
       let disposed = false
       exchangeCode(code)
           .then(() => {
               if (disposed) return
               setError(null)
               window.history.pushState({}, null, "/")
           })
           .catch(error => {
               if (disposed) return
               console.error(error)
               setError(error)
           })

        return () => disposed = true
    }, [code])

    if (error !== null) {
        return <span class="error">{error.message}</span>
    }

    if (code) {
        // TODO: Render progress bar/spinner/throbber for "Signing in..."
        return /* ... */
    }

    // if here, no code & no error. Show login button
    // TODO: Render login button
    return /* ... */
}
```

```
// MyRouter.js (rename it however you like)
import useSpotify from '...'
import Login from '...'

const MyRouter = () => {
    const { hasToken } = useSpotify()

    if (!hasToken) {
        // No access token available, show login screen
        return <Login />
    }
   
    // Access token available, show main content
    return (
        <Router>
            // ...
        </Router>
    )
}
```

```
// App.js
import SpotifyAuthContextProvider from '...'
import MyRouter from '...'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <SpotifyAuthContextProvider>
             <MyRouter />
        </SpotifyAuthContextProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out, but the ```exchangeCode```  function is throwing an error of bad request 400, how to resolve that and sorry but can you please explain how this code is working because I am not fully understand.

Comment: @Amogh This code is your code from your question, just rearranged into a React `Context`. The contents of the `exchangeCode`  function are taken straight from the question. If you are getting a Error 400 from that code, you'll need to look into your `server.js` file for the cause and debug that yourself.

Comment: I fixed that error now, but how to remove the access_token and refresh_token from local storage on reload?

Comment: Sorry, but a new error 429 is coming now, which means that the api has requested data too many times. How to fix this?

Comment: @Amogh StackOverflow isn't designed for one-on-one code debugging of every problem with your code. You ask one specific question and get an answer for that specific problem. Have a new problem? Ask a new question. If you are looking for someone to go over all your code, hire a freelancer. Regarding clearing the data (on log out, doing it on reload would annoy your users) you would use `localStorage.removeItem('myApp:spotify')`. Regarding Error 429, see the [docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#rate-limiting). I'll add more comments when I'm free.